# Processing http-POST in apache web server

Tags: php, node.js, apache, http-post

I have Apache Web Server running to server a website (using angular.js), Now I am going to add Authentication to my website. The Authentication which I am going to use returns me POST request with user token.

Now I need to process the token, If he is valid user I need to give him access to my website.

As I should process the POST Request, I found there is little support for Apache Web Server like [apreq](https://httpd.apache.org/apreq/docs/libapreq2/).

So, I am thinking to replace apache with php or node.js. So are there other ways to process POST method request in Apache or which would be better alternative among php or node.js?